# From which year do MacBook keyboards have no issues?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Firstly, apologies for the somewhat vague, somewhat subjective question. I search for this question on Google and have spent the past 20 minutes wading through clickbait and misinformation along the lines of:

[image]

**Define *issues***:

- Dust accumulation behind keys causing a single keypress to cause n != 1 keypresses to register (mostly 2 or 0).

**Define *no issues***:

- What is considered normal for any properly functioning hardware (my guess is 1/10,000 perhaps? - so 1/10 devices would definitely be problematic)

#### Question

Starting which year can someone buy a MacBook Pro and be sure with a high degree of certainty that they're getting a functioning keyboard?

Comment: I think dust is a bit hyperbolic. I don’t dispute many people had lost function, multiple repairs, but sand or grit would be needed to disable a key. My personal data is the butterfly models are more reliable than the scissors ones and only Apple (or. Company with thousands of machines entering service a year has enough data to know if the 2019 / 2020 are more reliable than the scissors era hardware.)

Comment: I love that this is a good subjective question. Clear criteria and asking for data and possibly verifiable conclusions to cut through the clear volume of noise and anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @bmike: no it's not hyperbolic. The big point about the 2016,2017 Chiclet v1 keyboard was that **keyboard failures could destroy an MBP, and Apple specifically excluded them from the warranty (in 2016/7 I believe)**. This was insane and (obviously) caused user backlash. Remember that since Apple transitioned MBPs around 2014 to non-repairable, non-upgradeable 'sealed unit', so essentially all failures now require ship replacement parts from factory, not while-you-wait or 2-day in an Apple Store. (Or where repair cost is about the same as replacement cost, the things are essentially disposable)

Comment: Keys work by physical motion. Only “magical” dust is somehow large enough to impact a physical switch. I’m not saying the problem isn’t real - adding the word dust is hyperbole. I don’t doubt the pain of actual physical damage or blockage to actual keyboards has caused or intend to lessen people’s pain. It’s just not ***dust*** that’s causing the pain that a duster can’t easily remove. Having that word in there lessens the rigor of a proper problem people face and lets people dismiss this IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, **any Apple laptop available for sale from May 2020** comes with a comparatively reliable keyboard.

To elaborate, the distinction you should be looking for is whether the laptop comes with a **Butterfly Switch** key mechanism vs **Scissor Switch** key mechanism.

When it comes to recent generation of Apple laptops, there are basically categorized into three distinct classes (increasing order of performance, decreasing order of portability):

1. [MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_(2015%E2%80%932019)) (marketed as New MacBook released between 2015-2019)
2. [MacBook Air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air)
3. [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro)

Apple first introduced Butterly Switch keyboard design with 2015 MacBook. Butterfly Switch keyboard featured flatter key design with lesser key travel, and an entirely new internal mechanism. Butterfly Switch design was then incorporated in the re-designed 2016 MacBook Pro lineup (13" and 15") and subsequently into 2018 13" MacBook Air.

Apart from having difference in terms of tactile feedback, key travel and user experience compared to the predecessor Scissor Switch design, (which could be subjective) Butterly key design, in general, performed poorly in terms of reliability compared to their ancestor Scissor Switch design.

Due to growing user concerns, the Butterly Switch design saw iterations over four generations where the internal mechanism was tweaked and new materials were used, but the reliability issues still persisted to an extent, causing Apple to launch the [Keyboard Service Program](https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks). Under the program, customers are eligible to get a service or even a replacement of keyboard if needed, free of cost.

However, starting recently with the introduction of **Late 2019 16" MacBook Pro** which was [released in November 2019](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2019/11/apple-introduces-16-inch-macbook-pro-the-worlds-best-pro-notebook/), Apple attempted to address the issue with an entirely overhauled and enhanced keyboard design based on Scissor Switch and re-branded it as **New Magic Keyboard**. The general response for the said Magic Keyboard has been

This scissor mechanism has been further adopted into **Early 2020 13" MacBook Air**, [released in March 2020](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/03/new-macbook-air-has-more-to-love-and-is-now-just-999/), and subsequently in **Mid 2020 13" MacBook Pro** [release in May 2020](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/05/apple-updates-13-inch-macbook-pro-with-magic-keyboard-double-the-storage-and-faster-performance/).

With this last release, the transition of the entire lineup of Apple laptops to use scissor switch is complete and they are all re-branded as the New Magic Keyboard.

Apple has [discontinued](https://www.theverge.com/2019/7/9/20687417/apple-discontinues-12-inch-macbook) MacBook from its laptop lineup in June 2019.

Comment: "The general response for the said Magic Keyboard has been"...?  The suspense is killing me.

Comment: @KirkWoll Haha. That gave me a chuckle. Well I cannot confidently, on record, claim that the New Magic Keyboard is absolutely, 100% reliable. Hence the language. But don't jink the "Magic" with your suspense.

Comment: Great contextual info! Is it possible to elaborate on 'comparatively reliable'? For example, I would describe every keyboard I've used in the past 20 years aside from 1 as 'extremely reliable', 'completely functional' etc. In layperson's terms: they 'worked 100% of the time'. Everything made by apple <= 2014 falls into this category. Does the late 2019 16'' Macbook Pro also fall into this (extremely close to) 100% reliable category, or are there lingering issues that make it less reliable? Sorry to nitpick, but it is very important to me.

Comment: @stevec I said "comparatively reliable", because so far people have found to be better at reliability compared to the Butterfly counterparts. Also, it still hasn't been a long time since they are released widely. So we can know only with time how well they fare.

Comment: I still think saying a keyboard is "comparatively reliable" (relative to the butterfly keyboard) is like saying a person is "comparatively trustworthy" (relative to Bernie Madoff). It is so broad as to tell us almost nothing. I do not know the market well enough (and cannot find sales figures), but I would have guessed the sales of 2019 16'', 2020 13'' MA, and 2020 13'' MBP would be sufficient to say by now whether the keyboard issues have been fixed? Especially since twitter + news blew up just weeks after the faulty keyboards of past models? Note: I could be wrong - just my thoughts

Comment: @stevec I think this couldn't be deduced from the sales numbers. And sales numbers may not be publicly available. However, I used the term "comparatively reliable" as the reviews have been generally positive and no negative news has blown up yet! 2020 models are still pretty new too.

Comment: I guess at some point, after enough time + sales, provided there aren't any complaints, it should eventually become possible to say that there are no keyboard issues from the 2019 16'' MacBook Pro onwards

Comment: @stevec I totally agree!

Comment: If I may jump in - hope not to hijack - if so let me know and ill start a new thread.  I have a new, since march 2020 MBP 16" and from time to time thought I was going nuts - the "I" and the "k" sometimes doubles - I get 2 of them.  Finally called apple today and have started to keep track of the repeating just to try and figure it out.  I hate to have to send it in but I also hate to have double letters.  So far today ive gotten double i's 3 times and a k once. 
I seriously doubt im pressing the keys twice and when I press and hold I don't get repeating letters anyhow.  I think its an issue.

Comment: @Stumped interesting. Sounds like Nimesh's caution is completely warranted. I wonder if there's public data available that can let us measure what proportion of magic keyboard users have experienced problems? (i.e. if it's extremely rare, or if it's happening a lot etc)

Comment: @stevec I suspect if any kind of public data would ever be available. The only avenue that we can keep any eye on is feedback, reviews and rants on the Internet and hoping major tech publications cover it.

Comment: gonna keep an eye on it and try to keep track of when it happens.  guess there is no keyboard test.  very weird and a bit frustrating to say the least.  good thing - still in warranty.

Comment: @Stumped - seems like there may be occasional issues with the MacBook Pro 16" from Nov 2019: [some reports](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-2019-15-inch-5-t-g-b-keys-not-working.2226770/) that a group of keys in same 'row' can fail at the same time.  Also, [slightly mis-hitting keys](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mbp-16-keyboard-still-problematic.2220285/) can mean they click but don't register key press.  Best to ask on forums like MacRumors but please write an answer here if you find anything useful.

Comment: will do.  tks for the tip.  oddly enough, coincidence probably, since I did PRAM & SMC reset I haven't seen any duplicate letters.  Anyhow keeping an eye on it.

Comment: Started to get the duplicating letters again and brought I to cert apple repair store. Got a call today that the T2 security chip was preventing them from doing any diagnostic scans.   Going to pick it up tomorrow to shop to apple.

Comment: MBP 2019 16” in for service for the past week for duplicating letters. Issue confirmed and duplicated and new keyboard ordered today.

Comment: just got MBP back.  they replaced top part of case and battery(includes keyboard).  We'll see if the issue is fixed - hadn't had a chance to use it much yet. Keys feel the same - except the power/fingerprint reader button.  It sits more flush(lower in case) and is easier to push down / much less force needed....

Answer (score 5):

If you’re looking for a general rule of thumb, anything from 2015 through 2019 had the “bad” keyboards.  It wasn’t until the 2019 16” MacBook Pro did they get rid of the horrible “butterfly keyboard mechanism:

They were introduced in the 2015 MacBook and were integrated into subsequent Macs after that.

- MacBook - 2015 through 2017.  They ended production of this model with the 2017 model year.
- MacBook Pro

  - 13” 2016 - 2019.  The new 2020 13” MBPs use the new Magic Keyboard
  - 15” 2016 - 2019.  All MBP modes from this line have the butterfly keyboard.  There has been no release of a 15” model for 2020
- MacBook Air - All MacBook Air models from 2015 through 2019 had the butterfly key.

All new models MacBook from 2020 onward will have the new Magic Keyboard (scissor) mechanism (until they change again, of course).

Comment: I wonder if Wikipedia or another site has a good chart on which keyboards were primarily scissor based and which were primarily butterfly based. One good resource to learn terms is [iMore and I trust Rene Ritchey for fair coverage](https://www.imore.com/macbook-pro-butterfly-keyboard-effect) that is technically excellent

Comment: That’s a good resource @bmike...I’ve run across many times in my travels.  I wrote the answer because I myself had this very question very recently and didn’t find any list.  Figured I’d just type up my findings.  :-)

Comment: What? The 2015 MBP keyboard is totally fine.

Comment: @DanielB +1. Here's the newsroom [article about 2016 MBP having "More responsive and comfortable typing on the keyboard with a second-generation butterfly mechanism;"](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2016/10/apple-unveils-groundbreaking-new-macbook-pro/)

Comment: Agree with @DanielB - the 2015 Air and MacBook Pro have the good keyboard.  I own both, so can confirm personally.  The bad ones start in 2016, not 2015.

Comment: @Haydentech - the question is about the problematic keyboards, not whether or not you liked typing on them. So, *objectively* for this answer to be correct, 2015 is when MacBooks were released with the butterfly keyboards.

Comment: By good, I meant non-butterfly.  Both the 2015 model year MacBook Pro and MacBook Air do NOT have a butterfly keyboard.  Your answer is wrong in regard to these two models.  Only the MacBook (non-Pro) had the butterfly keyboard in 2015: see https://www.macrumors.com/guide/butterfly-keyboard-issues/

Comment: First off I said "for a general rule of thumb."  Secondly, that was a typo in the bullet proints, but thanks for the down vote.

Comment: since the last post where i disabled repeating letters under keyboard options, i continue to get some double letters, "i" being the most frequent.  I do not get them on my 2011 apple keyboard for my Imac or my wifes 2017 mbp.  Im thinking now my problem was not fixed when they replaced my 2019, 16" MBP keyboard

Answer (score -3):

It depends what you mean by "bad" in terms of the failure rate, and on how much you believe the hype around it. I have a MacBook Air with one of the butterfly ("bad") keyboards and have had no problems with it at all. I'm sure most people with the the same keyboard also have had no problems. I think it's too early to determine whether or not the new designed keyboard is more reliable since it's only been out for a month or so.

Comment: That would be, as they say, **wrong.** The MacBook Pro 16-inch was introduced in November of 2019 (so at least 7 months) with the so called "Magic Keyboard" with a more reliable scissor switch design. Look up reviews and so far this keyboard looks to be a whole lot more reliable than the previous generation "butterfly" keyboards. Granted not everyone had problems but they *were indeed* more problematic for more people. So you are more likely to have a better result with a MacBook with the newer scissor switch keyboard.

Comment: I bought a 16" one on the launch day and have been using it every, single, day. Having used a 15" 2018 MacBook Pro before, I can definitely see that the New Magic Keyboard won't have a similar fate.

Comment: I got the last release of the 2015 15" MacBook Pro with a scissor switch and used it as my daily driver until September 2019. So four years of heavy use. Never had a key issue, never had to clean under the keys.

I replaced that with a Mid-2019 15" MacBook Pro (so the latest/last generation with butterfly keys), and had to do the "hang it upside down and hit it with compressed air under the key" trick to fix a sticky key for the first time last month. I don't eat around my laptop or operate it in dusty environments, YMMV. I prefer the feel of the butterfly keyboard, but debris is a risk.