# how to get repeating letters on 2019 16" MacBook Pro keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

so, as part of maybe, [From which year do MacBook keyboards have no issues?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392126/from-which-year-do-macbook-keyboards-have-no-issues/392131#comment539353_392131)

I have tried different settings w/ apple cs the other day to try and get the I, K and L to duplicate as happens to me sometimes.  Of course they didnt.  However, neither of us could get any letter to repeat when pressing and continuing to hold a key.  I could not see a setting in preferences and the rep couldnt figure out how either.  Can anyone tell me how to get repeating letters by pressing and holding a key?  When I do it in this screen nothing happens.  In pages if I press and hold the e lets say, a tiny window with a  capital "E" opens and closes and while continuing to hold the key, the letter does not repeat.

Tks

Answer (score 3):

Since 2011 default behavior in Mac OS has been for letter keys to not repeat when held down. Instead the Character Picker or Accent Menu appears where appropriate. Nothing to do with the link you mention.  To get repeating keys, try opening Terminal and typing

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

and then restart.

In Pages if you press and hold e, you should get what is shown below if your OS is working properly.

[image]

Comment: tks.  wasn't sure as this is my 1st MBP.  Could have sworn that on my 2011 iMac w/ Bluetooth keyboard I got repeating letters and seeing as im now having issues w/ double I,K & L's and was troubleshooting w/ the rep yesterday I thought id ask.  They seemed surprised too that we were not getting them to repeat.  May  have been on the cusp w/ the 2011 for repeating letters ???  Tks again

Comment: It's the OS rather than the hardware, so 10.7 started the non-repeating.

Comment: Question - if its standard not to have repeating letters, why to they have "Key Repeat" in preferences?  Im still having some letters repeating at times.  The Apple tech said to keep an eye on it.  Happens very sporadically and I could not get them to duplicate in a short screen sharing session.  I don't get it - very frustrating to have this but I know ive never had typing issues on any other keyboard.....

Comment: Lots of keys repeat even when letters do not.  Space, Delete, punctuation, symbols, etc.

Comment: So I have started to have repeating letters on and off again while typing. I’ve disabled the repeating letters option in keyboard preferences to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: since the last post, i continue to get some double letters still, "i" being the most frequent.  I do not get them on my 2011 apple keyboard for my Imac or my wifes 2017 mbp.  Im thinking now my problem was not fixed when they replaced my 2019, 16" MBP keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If by chance your install does allow key repeat (and presumably has no Accent Menus on Press and Hold), you can go to System Preferences/Keyboard. Make sure you are on the Keyboard tab at the top. On this panel, you can set the time between keys repeating or you can turn it off completely. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: But playing with these settings will normally not do anything with most keys if you have not disabled default behavior via the terminal.  Or do you find otherwise?  Do your I  K L E repeat?

Comment: yes my keys repeat. k,l,e and others i tried.

Comment: I didn't know the terminal command so I haven't run it. In the control panel I show there is an option to turn off key repeating.

Comment: yep I have the above too - key repeat and delay until repeat.  They seem to have no effect other than how fast the cursor deletes and how long I have to wait before it starts deleting and how long the capital box stays on screen when holding a key.  I get no repeating letters - other than the occasional double(which is not what I am referring to here)  I, K and L issue im keeping track of.

Comment: Which MacOS version are you using?

Comment: High Sierra.  10.13.6

Comment: If you would like to have the popup accent menus sometime, just change the “false” in the terminal command to “true”.

Comment: 10.15.5 Catalina